# How can we disable zooming function of ion-slide in ionic4

Tags: ionic4, ion-slides

How can we disable the zooming function of `ion-slides` in Ionic 4, I already tried adding `zoom="false"` input on `ion-slides` element but it's not working, when I am double tapping on the screen it's still zooming the image and breaking the design.

Answer (score 13):

You can disable zoom using below code in options of ion-slides in your ts file.

```
  slideOpts = {
    zoom: false
  };


  <ion-slides [options]="slideOpts">
      <ion-slide>..</ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Comment: Is there any way to check current zoom scale? I have set max ratio as below, but while zooming, I am not getting current scale?
`sliderOpts = {
    zoom: {
      maxRatio: 5
    }
  };`